# When I call one sidebar multiple sidebars appear. How to fix?

Tags: wordpress

I have a functions.php file where I registered all sidebars.

In the sidebar.php file I have this

```
<?php if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar('Home Page') ) : ?>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar('Blog Page') ) : ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

then I call it

```
 <?php get_sidebar('Home Page'); ?>
```

yet Blog Page sidebar is showing up too. What to do?

edit:
Wait am I going to need to create a page for all of my sidebars? Is that why it's not working?

That is going to be a lot of pages is there any other way around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do this slightly differently, I do:

This in my functions.php:

```
    // header
    register_sidebar( array (
    'name' => 'Header Widget Area',
    'id' => 'header_widget_area',
    'before_widget' => '<li id="%1$s" class="widget-container %2$s">',
    'after_widget' => "</li>",
    'before_title' => '<h3 class="widget-title">',
    'after_title' => '</h3>',
    ) );

    // Single Post Sidebar
    register_sidebar( array (
    'name' => 'Single Widget Area',
    'id' => 'single_widget_area',
    'before_widget' => '<li id="%1$s" class="widget-container %2$s">',
    'after_widget' => "</li>",
    'before_title' => '<h3 class="widget-title">',
    'after_title' => '</h3>',
  ) );
```

I then call them like so in which ever template I'm using them:

```
<?php if ( is_sidebar_active('header_widget_area') ) : ?>
        <?php dynamic_sidebar('header_widget_area'); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Let me know if you need more help.

Answer (score 0):

The command dynamic_sidebar() actually outputs the indicated sidebar.  When you call get_sidebar, it is displaying both of those sidebars because in the conditional, the sidebar is outputted.

You are not quite on the right path for what you want.

You are going to want to simply have

```
get_sidebar();
```

in your templates.

Then in the sidebar.php file you would do conditionals to determine when to show what.  For example, something like this...

```
if ( is_page() ) :
    dynamic_sidebar('page-sidebar');
elseif ( is_post() ) :
    dynamic_sidebar('post-sidebar');
endif;
```

Let me know if you are still having trouble and I can give more details / a better more detailed solution example